# Suddenly cannot access HTTP from outside (AWS EC2 Linux)

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

This website was running for almost a year. And suddenly can't access HTTP from outside.  Apache is running. I can access my website from the server (curl -I http://127.0.0.1). But I cannot access it from the outside (say http://www.example.com, and no access logs at all).  The last access log captured got lots of post request (POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.1" 200 593 "-").
I tried restarting the apache server and then rebooting the server. The problem still exists. And I already looked at the AWS console security group (both 80 and 443 are allowed). And I do not have any firewall installed on the server (iptables -L - ALL chains policy ALLOW). From the flow log of the network interface, I always got some SSH requests from the unknown IPs.
Note: I cannot generate the log for web access every time I access the website. And the source IP is not from my machine. That is very strange. chkrootkit shows no infections as well. Is the server compromised?  Any other things I need to check? And how to get my webserver back and running?

Flow log:

```
version account-id interface-id srcaddr dstaddr srcport dstport protocol<br> packets bytes start end action log-status<br>
2 059258984213 eni-04fde3019d28f90a6 XX.XX.XX.XX 172.31.XX.XX 80 42232 6 8<br> 4635 1571307313 1571307320 ACCEPT OK<br>
2 059258984213 eni-04fde3019d28f90a6 172.31.XX.XX XX.XX.XX.XX 42232 80 6 6 412 <br>
1571307313 1571307320 ACCEPT OK<br>
2 059258984213 eni-04fde3019d28f90a6 XX.XX.XX.XX 172.31.XX.XX 63562 22 6 17<br> 2758 1571307370 1571307371 ACCEPT OK<br>
2 059258984213 eni-04fde3019d28f90a6 172.31.XX.XX XX.XX.XX.XX 22 63562 6 10<br> 2509 1571307370 1571307371 ACCEPT OK<br>
2 059258984213 eni-04fde3019d28f90a6 172.31.XX.XX XX.XX.XX.XX 42230 80 6 7 478<br> 1571307337 1571307345 ACCEPT OK<br>
2 059258984213 eni-04fde3019d28f90a6 172.31.XX.XX XX.XX.XX.XX 42234 80 6 7 475<br> 1571307337 1571307345 ACCEPT OK<br>
2 059258984213 eni-04fde3019d28f90a6 XX.XX.XX.XX 172.31.XXXX 80 42230 6 8 3357<br> 1571307337 1571307345 ACCEPT OK<br>
2 059258984213 eni-04fde3019d28f90a6 XX.XX.XX.XX 172.31.XXXX 80 42234 6 7 2283<br> 1571307337 1571307345 ACCEPT OK<br>
2 059258984213 eni-04fde3019d28f90a6 - - - - - - - 1571307379 1571307392 - <br>NODATA
```

Comment: "I cannot access it from the outside" meaning what? Do you get a DNS error, HTTP error, SSL error, connection timeout, what? The mode of failure will dictate the troubleshooting.

Comment: Not a DNS error, and log shows no HTTP error or SSL error.  The browser just shows "The Site can't be reached - ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: Did you try to access from another computer?

Comment: Yes, already did.  But still no good.